# Add checkbox in table in pine script v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is it posibble to add checkbox in table that is overlayed on tradingview chart?
I have checkbox in inout settings that shows or hide some lines, but is it possible to add checkbox in table overlayed on chart and show/hide lines from there?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to create checkbox / Buttons on charts, if your objective is to display data/Information , you can achieve this by utilizing label tooltips , label with Icon & on click it show you the Information's as text

Comment: My checkbox is showing or hiding indicator, so informations like text is not very helpful